# How to configure datacontrol in ADF mobile to access secured webservice?

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf

1) How can i invoke secured web service using "Webservice datacontrol" in ADF Mobile. I searched in google and got a link by andrejus "**http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2012/11/adf-mobile-secured-web-service-access.html**", but not understanding about "adfCredentialStoreKey", what is it? and how can i use it?. I set the security policies as mentioned, is it enough to invoke the secured webservices without giving username/password?. When and why we should go with selecting security policy?? what is the use of it? Bit confused, **can anyone please tell me more about accessing secured webservices from webservice datacontrol**.

2) I deployed on-device mobile application into Android emulator. For remote debugging followed the steps given in ADF mobile developer's guide. However still remote debugging is not working. Throwing this message in console "**Debugger unable to connect to remote process**" . How can i fix it?

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog and video demo that shows how to do this - https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from

Comment: Thank you Shay.. you posted new demo regarding this for people like us, awesome :) This demo & Andrejus sample helps me a lot to do sample authentication using "**Remote login server**". Small doubt, Is it possible to inject user credentials with webservice request without creating **"regular" web ADF application, secure it, and deploy it on a server** . I read it in mobile document,

Comment: conti.. **For secured web services, the user credentials are dynamically injected using ADF Mobile uses Oracle Web Services Manager (OWSM) Lite Mobile ADF Application Agent to create and configure proxies, as well as to request services through the proxies. The user credentials are injected into the OWSM enforcement context when proxies are configured.**

**I am new with this OWSM, can you please give me some hints like how to proceed further for implementing authentication using OWSM lite mobile ADF Application Agent.**

Thanks in advance